# Translate reserved fields in admin Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, backend, translate

I'm trying to translate the label of each fields which is described in below screen shot. I'm using Magento 2.1.6.

[image]

I have created a language pack in this directory: `app/i18n/xxx/yyy/magento2-pt_br/module-backend.csv`

Also I have executed the following commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && chmod 777 -R var && chmod 777 -R pub

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR --theme xxx/yyyy_zzzz

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR --theme Magento/backend

cd var && rm -R *

php bin/magento setup:upgrade && chmod 777 -R var && chmod 777 -R pub
```

But `labels` are not getting translated with my custom `csv` file. I do not know what else to do. Thanks for any help.